# Is anybody aware of a mature Java library which will help me query a Hudson / Jenkins server

Tags: java, python, ant, hudson, jenkins

I'm primarily a Python developer working in an environment where just about every important batch is run by a Hudson or Jenkins server. I've written a python library which uses Hudson's python API which allows me trivially write Hudson clients in Python.

I'm looking for a Java class which will help me do the same kinds of things, but without any Python.

The neat thing about my home-made python library is that it allows me to work at a very high-level. Consumers of my library are entirely shielded from the complexities of what goes on within Hudson. Most of the things I need to do can be expressed in one-line functions:

For example I can search for and download artifacts. I can find jobs whose results match certain criteria. I can even remotely trigger jobs or query the status of jobs. The only problems with my library are that for boring legal reasons it must remain closed-source, and being Python I've no hope of being able to integrate it into Ant.

I'd like to make a lot of my Hudson magic work from Ant scripts - and for this I need to re-implement some of my Hudson stuff as an ant-task in Java. For that I'd need a java library which exposes a lot of what Hudson does at a high level. Does such a project exist? If so can you let me know where I can find it?

---

Updated: I already built a Python based solution [Python Jenkins API](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jenkinsapi) - I'm after a Java equivalent of this.

Answer (score 2):

[jenkins cli](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI)

is that what you need?